# How do I set a built in variable in awk command to global variable?

Tags: bash, shell, variables, awk

Currently, my script parses through a file and looks for specific patterns. Each pattern is different from the other and are mutually exclusive within the file. e.g. If '$identifier1' is found, then '$identifier2' and '$identifier3' cannot be in the file.

```
exist=`awk -v v1="$identifer1" -v v2="$identifier2" -v v3="$identifier3" 'BEGIN{FS=":"; OFS="-"} $2 == v1 || $2 == v2 || $2 == v3 {print}' $file`
```

Here is the issue: during the comparison ($2 == v1 || $2 == v2 || $2 == v3), how can I set $2 as a global variable where I can use it outside of the awk command?

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: You can't. If you update your question to describe what you're trying to do (print something? save some value to a file? populate a shell variable?) rather than how you're trying to do it (make $2 available outside of the awk script) then we can help you do whatever it is you're trying to do.

Answer (score 0):

Could you please try following once but your question is not clear. In case you want to check a different field than 2nd then change value of variable named `field_value` and `awk` will look for that specific field then.

```
field_value="2"
exist=$(awk -v v1="$identifer1" -v v2="$identifier2" -v v3="$identifier3" -v field="$field_value" 'BEGIN{FS=":"; OFS="-"} $field == v1 || $field == v2 || $field == v3 {print}' "$file")
```

Answer (score 0):

Maybe can't directly, but if a temporary IO is ok with you...
You can write `$2` to a temporary file and later read into variable, like this:

```
exist=`awk -v v1="$identifer1" -v v2="$identifier2" -v v3="$identifier3" 'BEGIN{FS=":"; OFS="-"} $2 == v1 || $2 == v2 || $2 == v3 {print} {printf $2>"_tmpfile_for_v_"}' $file`
tmpv=$(<_tmpfile_for_v_)
rm _tmpfile_for_v_
```

Now you can use the `$tmpv` stored `$2`.

Btw the `awk` command can improve a little bit:

```
awk -v v1="$identifer1" -v v2="$identifier2" -v v3="$identifier3" 'BEGIN{FS=":"; OFS="-"} {printf $2>"_tmpfile_for_v_"} $2 == v1 || $2 == v2 || $2 == v3 ' $file
```

Where no block given, `{print}` is implied.

Answer (score 0):

You did not give testdata, so I will demonstrate how you can set an extra variable with a simplified question.
Suppose you have a file with only one line starting with 1 (a line like `1 2 3`).
How can you use `awk` for filling two variables, one with the line starting with 1 and one with the second field?
You can find the line with

```
   line=$(awk '/^1/ {print}' file)
```

Now you would like to do something like

```
  awk '/1^/ {print "line=" $0; print "field2=" $2}' file
```

When you know that the line doesn't has a `#`, you can use

```
IFS='#" read -r line field2 <<< $(awk '/^1/ {print $0 "#" $2}' file
```